# For one Amazon EC2 Instance, what paid service for free SSL Certificate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

I have one EC2 Instance but need an SSL Certificate and am wanting the free one offered thru Amazon.  However I need to use another paid service. With just one (most likely low volume) EC2 instance I doubt I need Elastic Load Balancing. The only other service that makes sense would be Amazon CloudFront.

I am running a website for an online store so the other paid services don't seem to apply.

Or should I just opt for a paid SSL Certificate from a 3rd party Certificate Authority and install it on my EC2 Instance?

Any guidance is really appreciated.

Comment: Not really an answer, but just buy the cert or use Let's Encrypt. Getting an ELB or CloudFront isn't worth the cost if you do it only for the cert.

Comment: Thanks Exelian.  You are the only response so think I will go with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I am  not sure if you know that Aws offers free SSL certificates. You can use those certificates with ELB and CloudFront.

Also, Aws won't charge anything for that SSL service.

So, you can work with CloudFront + SSL -> EC2.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score -1):

I think it really depends on what type of information you are gathering from the user visiting the site. If you are collecting sensitive data, then yes, I would recommend the purchase of a SSL certificate.

Users may not feel comfortable entering in data on an insecure website.

I thought this [link](https://www.safecomputing.umich.edu/dataguide/?q=node/89) to a webpage on University of Michigan's website gave good examples of what could be considered sensitive data.